# Nativescript Angular binding Image to view not working

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to take a picture with the camera or select one from the gallery, then display it on my view(As simple as that).
But the avatar is not updating after I set the new value in the camera.takePicture callback, as shown bellow.

```
// template
<Image col="0" [src]="avatar" class="thumb img-rounded" width="45" height="45" verticalAlignment="middle"></Image>


// component
camera.requestPermissions();
let options = {
       width: this.width,
       height: this.height,
       keepAspectRatio: this.keepAspectRatio,
       saveToGallery: this.saveToGallery,
       format: 'png'
  };

camera.takePicture(options)
.then(imageAsset => {
  this.avatar = imageAsset // update view with new image
  this.uploadImage()  // upload on the server
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('error---', err.message);
});
```

Angular seems not to be detecting the changes.The same Image I'm trying to show on my view, Is being successfully uploaded to my server using nativescript-background-http.

Here is my environment:

```
 "tns-ios": "version": "3.0.0"
"tns-android": "version": "3.0.0"
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"tns-core-modules": "~3.0.0"
"nativescript-camera": "^3.0.0"
```

The Issue happening on both IOS and Android.

I have tried triggering change detection with ApplicationRef, NgZone and ChangeDetectorRef, but without success.

Is there any working example of how to use the camera module to take a picture and bind the Image to the view?

Thanks

Comment: What library you're using to take the pictures? An API from that would clarify what's the problem.
Another thing is what's the value of `this.avatar` here it has to be real path to file not data.

Comment: @PRAISER I'm using **nativescript-camera**. Even when I set `this.avatar = path-to-a-static-image-no-my-server`, it doesn't show up on the view. In fact, anything I do in the "takePicture" callback doesn't update the view.

Comment: My advice: make sure `nativescript-camera` works out of context of `Angular` first.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had it working!  Actually I was making a mistake, by passing a static array to the listview. So angular seems to be updating the template only if the array passed to listview as "items" has changed. ngZone.run was also needed to make it work.

```
 <ListView   class="list-group"   [items]="[1, 2]">
   <template> 
  // Image code
  </template>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Hi Rolland, I think I am having the same issue, but you solution is rather insufficient. Can you please clarify what works for you?

Comment: @nbo can you show me  your code? running your handlers code inside zone.run()。 should be ok. But if that doesn't work you might also have some template issues.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It turned out my issue was not related - I was using <NSImage> tag (which doesn't get updated) when I should have been using a generic <Image> tag.